# How I can replace <br /> with " " in a function

Tags: php, html

```
 <?php
 function show(){?>
     <?php  echo "a"; ?>  <br />
 }
 //this function is in another file
 <?php
     echo str_replace("<br />"," ",show());//search for  <br />
 ?>
```

How i can replace the `<br />` with `" "`?

Comment: how i can replace <br /> with " " after i call function show() ?

Comment: You can [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30246760/edit) if you need to change/add information.

Comment: Please provide some information and differentiation between your question your code and your comming output and your desired output.

Answer (score 3):

You need to buffer the output.  Something similar to this:

```
ob_start();
show();
echo str_replace("<br />", " ", ob_get_clean());
```

Comment: It's worth noting that there are variations of `<br />`.

Comment: @Devon should make that non-greedy and I don't think you'd need the grouping, `#<br.*?>#`

Comment: For variations, you could use `preg_replace('#<br.*?>#i', ' ', $str);`.  This would work for `<br>`, `<br >`, `<br />` all case insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a callback in combination with [`ob_start`](http://php.net/ob_start). The callback will be called each time the output is flushed.

```
function replace_br($buffer)
{
    return preg_replace('~<br\b[^>]*>~i', ' ', $buffer);
}
ob_start('replace_br');
```

---

The regular expressions says:

- find the string '

  the char after should not be alphanumeric

  find any characters others than '>'

  find an '>'

This replaces `<br>`, `<BR>`, `<br/>`, `<br />` but also something like `<br class="clearfix">`.